# How to filter an array's fields in a DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working on JSON files with DataFrames, and I can't achieve to filter an array's fields.

This is my input struct :

```
root
 |-- MyObject: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Field1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Field2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Field3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Field3_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Field3_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Field3_3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Field3_3: string (nullable = true)
```

and I want a DF like that :

```
root
 |-- Field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Field3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Field3_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Field3_3: string (nullable = true)
```

The best I got is with

```
df.select($"MyObject.Field1",
          $"MyObject.Field3.Field3_1" as "Field3.Field3_1",
          $"MyObject.Field3.Field3_3" as "Field3.Field3_3")
```

which gives me :

```
root
 |-- Field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Field3_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Field3_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (nullable = true)
```

I can't use `array` function because Field3_1 and Field3_3 haven't the same type.

How can I create an array with only selected fields?

I'm a beginner with Spark SQL, maybe I'm missing something!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a udf function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def arraystructUdf = udf((f3:Seq[Row])=> f3.map(row => field3(row.getAs[Boolean]("Field3_1"), row.getAs[String]("Field3_3"))))

df.select(col("MyObject.Field1"), arraystructUdf(col("MyObject.Field3")).as("Field3"))
```

where field3 is a case class

```
case class field3(Field3_1:Boolean, Field3_3:String)
```

which should give you

```
root
 |-- Field1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Field3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Field3_1: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- Field3_3: string (nullable = true)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks it's working like a charm!  
I have to extract 70 fields from my array, so a `case class` can't do the job, and without I loose the fields' name, any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by case class can't do the job? did you try ? what was the error? other alternative would be to explode field3, select the 70 elements from the exploded struct and then finally combine the exploded and selected struct into array using array inbuilt function

Comment: I had not tested because I thought the 22 fields limit was still  here in 2.11, but it is working, thanks.

Comment: the limit is still there for  tuples but they removed the limit for case classes in new versions (don't remember the version)

Comment: I now have one of the fields of Field3 which need to be retrieved from another DataFrame, but I can't access it from UDF. It would be perfect as a broadcasted Map (I want a value from the key "Field3_3") but all my DataFrames are to big for broadcasting. How can I do that?

Comment: join is the only way left for you then

Comment: But how can I join with a DF for each elem of Field3? I could explode my array but I then will need to merge it after the join, I don't know how to do that. Moreover I need to join with 15 different DFs and at the end I have more than 200 fields, I'm afraid doing explodes then join then merge again and again will result in an ugly unreadable and undebugable code..

Comment: yes you are absolutely correct. And joins, explode and udfs are the most expensive transformations in spark dataframe/datasets. you have to architect it with care. One thing you can do if possible is to narrow down the other dfs and use them in broadcast

Comment: Is it better to have DFs in broadcast(df) (but that I can't use in my UDFs) or Broadcast[Map[String, Any]] that I can access in my UDFs to enrich?

Comment: you can use broadcast function for joining. without joining you can't use another dataframe in udf function

Comment: I'm moving on and facing new problems that I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324392/extract-a-nested-array-from-a-spark-sql-row-inside-a-udf), if you can take a look. If you know some resources (books/blogs/etc) where I could find answers and understand better Spark SQL and stop bothering you, please share ;) Thanks a lot for your help