# Extract a nested array from a Spark SQL Row inside a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with DataFrames and need to extract data.
I have many nested levels, so I did the first level with explodes and selects but then I use UDFs for nested levels.

I have an UDF taking `$"Root.Obj"`, which is an array, and I want it to return an Array[MyObj].
My output classes :

```
case class MyObj(fieldA: Boolean, fieldB: String, fieldC: Array[MyNested])
case class MyNested(field1: Long, field2: String)
```

This is the input schema in short :

```
 |-- Obj: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- FieldA: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FieldB: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FieldC: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Field1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Field2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- FieldD: boolean (nullable = true)
```

My UDFs :

```
def extractObjs: UserDefinedFunction = udf {
  (objs: Seq[Row]) ⇒
    objs.map {
      obj ⇒
        MyObj(
          obj.getAs[Boolean]("FieldA"),
          obj.getAs[String]("FieldB"),
          extractNested(obj.get???("FieldC"))
        )
    }
}

def extractNested(nesteds: ???): Array[MyNested] = {
  ???
}
```

This is more complicated IRL as I need to retrieve values from other places and there is more nested arrays.
Moreover, the input structures of Obj and FieldC are far more complex than here and I can't (or don't want) create case class for them. As I'll need to do this in over places, let's say I don't know "the struct" of FieldC elements.

My problem is to extract the "FieldC" array. I would like a Seq[Row] but I couldn't achieve to get that, getStruct give me just a Row, and getSeq[Row] is throwing error after because `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.

Comment: you should extract fieldC as  `Seq[Row]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structs map to `Row` in an UDF, so array of structs can be accessed by `Seq[Row]`, such as :

```
def extractObjs: UserDefinedFunction = udf {
  (objs: Seq[Row]) ⇒
    objs.map {
      obj ⇒
        MyObj(
          obj.getAs[Boolean]("FieldA"),
          obj.getAs[String]("FieldB"),
          extractNested(obj.getAs[Seq[Row]]("FieldC"))
        )
    }
}

def extractNested(nesteds: Seq[Row]): Array[MyNested] = {
  nesteds.map(r => MyNested(r.getAs[Long]("Field1"),r.getAs[String]("Field2"))).toArray
}
```

Comment: When I do that, I have a cast error as I said at the end of my post.

Comment: I don't know where I mistook in my tests but it's now working indeed. Thanks